# Como fazer um paginador sem que exista uma gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um sistema em asp net mvc, em uma das telas é exibido diversos itens, o select para pegar eles do banco é:

```
Select top 20 from Produtos
```

Como demonstrado, ele exibe apenas os vinte primeiros produtos. Os produtos são renderizados dentro de diversas divs, alimentadas por um foreach.
Algo assim:

```
foreach(var itens in produtos){
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6" id="produtos">
@itens.nomeProduto
</div>
</div>
}
```

Porém eu queria trazer todos os produtos, e exibir apenas vinte, e fazer uma espécie de paginador no rodapé.

A pergunta é, depois de eu trazer todos os produtos, como eu posso pegar os primeiros 20, e depois os proximos 20, e depois os proximos e assim por diante?

Comment: Não seria interessante fazer isso através da sua consulta, trazendo 20 por vez, ao invés de trazer todos e paginar de 20 em 20? Acho que aliviaria a sua requisição e também o handler destes dados.
Não programo em asp, só gostaria de colocar a idéia.

Comment: A idéia é essa mesma. O botão próximo deveria recarregar produtos chamando a funçção e passando o offset para ficar `TOP 20 OFFSET 20`vai trazer do 21 ao 40

Comment: Usa o [DataTable - Table plug-in for jQuery](https://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Use o seguinte pacote:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/

Uso:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? pagina)
{
    var produtos = contexto.Produtos; //traga todos os produtos aqui

    var numeroDaPagina = pagina ?? 1; // Se for nulo, coloca na primeira.
    var umaPaginaDeProdutos = produtos.ToPagedList(numeroDaPagina, 20); // 20 produtos apenas

    ViewBag.UmaPaginaDeProdutos = umaPaginaDeProdutos;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lista de Produtos"
}
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

<h2>Lista de Produtos</h2>
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.UmaPaginaDeProdutos) {
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="produtos">
            @item.nomeProduto
        </div>
    </div>
}

@* Navegador de Páginas *@
@Html.PagedListPager( (IPagedList)ViewBag.UmaPaginaDeProdutos, page => Url.Action("Index", new { pagina = page }) )
```

Mais exemplo? https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList